# Handle the response of writeValue in the method where writeValue is called? Possible?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-bluetooth

i need to compare the response of my writeValue with an expected string.

Ive created a Button to send the command:

```
- (IBAction)pair:(id)sender {
NSString * test = @"0/PAIR/START";

NSData *data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic: hr_characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
NSLog(@"send");
}
```

My peripherals returns: 0/OK or 0/ERROR

Now i want to compare the response in the method with the string i expect. Is this possible to evaluate in the method? Do i need a timer?

Ive a big pool of commands. How should i organize this pool of commands?

//sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does your peripheral emulate a serial port?  You don't get a response in `writeValueForCharacteristic`. You need to either read a characteristic or (better) set up notification on the characteristic that returns the status from your peripheral

Comment: i get an response. Remote[2534:60b] 0/READY. I set the Notificaton.[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic: hr_characteristic];

Comment: I need to compare the string i get out of didUpdateValueForCharacteristic with my ones. But this should happen in the button method

Comment: It can't happen in the button method because the notification is asynchronous - you need to keep track of your current state and validate the response once it is received.

Comment: I played around with a timer but I've a feeling that theres a better way to do this. Especially if i send 2 or 3 commands shortly after each other the response is overwritten every time. yea thats the problem. Ok thanks for your help @Paulw11

Comment: A timer is wrong because that is effectively polling which isn't efficient. You can either not send the next command until the previous command had been verified or you can keep a queue of expected responses and check each time a response is received in `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`